# Where to find GLSLEditorSample (GLSL IDE)?

Tags: macos, ide, glsl

Currently I'm doing some GLSL-stuff and to my surprise I cannot find a reasonable IDE for this (MacOS). Nothing to fancy, but just a way to change the code and see the results. I know of the Shadertoy-website, but I'm more interested in an offline solution.

So I came across the built-in OpenGL Shader Builder. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Developer_Tools#OpenGL_Shader_Builder), this is deprecated and superseded by *GLSLEditorSample*, which should still be available as an example project for XCode (of which I have version 7.3.1 installed). However, I basically cannot find anything about this, online nor on my computer. Therefor my question: Is this still relevant? If so, where is it located?

*PS: if you know of any other GLSL IDEs, I'm open to that as well*

Answer (score 0):

Here they explain how to setup OpenGL on a MacOS on Xcode:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tz0dq2krCW8&list=PLRtjMdoYXLf6zUMDJVRZYV-6g6n62vet8

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately this is not a solution to my problem. I want to find an easier way to write GLSL-shader (e.g. an IDE with syntax highlighting and preferably near-instantanious compilation), while this video seems to be about setting up OpenGL (which I already did).